# LS estimator variance derivation

Tags: expected-value, variance, parameter-estimation

I am struggling to understand the final step of the below derivation from my machine learning textbook (Section 3.6 of Machine Learning: A Bayesian and Optimization Perspective, 2e).

Let $y_n=\theta+\eta_n$ where $\theta$ is some constant and $\eta_n$ are $N$ noise samples from a normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma_{\eta}^2$, and $\bar{y}$ represent the sample mean. The variance of the estimator $\bar{y}$ is derived as follows:

\begin{align}
\sigma^2_{\bar{y}} & = \mathbb{E}\left[(\bar{y}-\theta)^2\right]
= \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{N^2}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N (y_n-\theta)\right)^2\right] \newline
& = \frac{1}{N^2}\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\sum_{n=1}^N \eta_n\right)^2\right]
= \frac{1}{N^2}\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^N \eta_i \sum_{j=1}^N \eta_j \right] \newline
&= \frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N \mathbb{E}[\eta_i \eta_j] = \frac{\sigma_{\eta}^2}{N}
\end{align}

I follow up until $$\frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N \mathbb{E}[\eta_i \eta_j] = \frac{\sigma_{\eta}^2}{N}$$ By what definition of variance does the above hold?

I know that $\textrm{Var}[x]=\mathbb{E}\left[\left(x-\mathbb{E}[x]\right)^2\right]=\mathbb{E}[x^2]-\mathbb{E}[x]^2$, and $\mathbb{E}[f(x)]=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N f(x_i)$, but neither of these seem to help here.

Comment: Are $\eta_i$ iid random variables?

Comment: Hint: consider when $i=j$ and when $i\neq j$.

Comment: Since $\eta_{I}$ and $\eta_{j}$ are real i.i.d, $\mathbb{E}\left[\eta_{i} \eta_{j} \right]=0 ,\forall I \ne j$. What remains (i.e., cases where $i =j$, it reflects as the variance $\sigma_{\eta}^{2}$ and total $N$ of them. Thus $\frac{1}{N^2} N \sigma_{\eta}^{2}$

Answer (score 1):

If $i \ne j$, if $\eta_i$ and $\eta_j$ are independent, then $E[\eta_i\eta_j]=E[\eta_i]E[\eta_j]=0\cdot 0=0$.

If $i=j$, then we have $e[\eta_i\eta_j]=E[\eta_i^2]=\sigma^2$.

Hence $$\frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{i,j}E[\eta_i\eta_j]=\frac1{N^2}\sum_i E[\eta^2]=\frac{N\sigma^2}{N^2}=\frac{\sigma^2}{N}.$$